# How to create an npm package that can be imported and wrapped around existing functionality?

Tags: node.js, express, npm, node-modules

I am new to creating node npm packages.

I am trying to create a package that can wrap around an existing express route and then import route into my npm package main js file to manipulate.

Example below:

```
const samplePackage = require('samplePackage');

<samplePackage>
app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({schema});
</samplePackage>
```

The intention of the package is to provide additional functionality to the endpoint.

Would this be possible at all? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible it to accomplish what you looking for by the use of Middleware,
There are lot available in Express,

For Example:
In your terminal:

```
npm install --save body-parser
```

Add this to your code:

```js
// Configuring body parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

**Or You can write a custom Middleware to meet your precise requirement also**